# C++ Sending a struct over a socket sometimes works

Tags: c++, sockets, struct, garbage

I'm trying to send a struct over a socket (I realize this is a non-portable solution, however, the client and server are Windows only - if there is a reasonably easy implementation of a more portable solution, I'm up for it).

This system sends a struct of doubles to the other socket, and the server is only a redirecter. Now, the first couple of structs come through properly, but at some point, I start getting garbage data and I can't figure out why.

Here is the code for the client:

```
struct aircraft_data {
    double altitude;
    double indicated_airspeed;
    double radio_altitude;
    double ground_altitude;
    double vertical_speed;
    double bank_angle;
    double pitch;
    double stall_aoa;
    double aoa;
    double on_ground;
    double sideslip;
    double heading_mag;
    double heading_true;
    double track_mag;
    double track_true;
    double eng_1_epr;
    double eng_2_epr;
    double eng_1_n1;
    double eng_2_n1;
    double eng_1_n2;
    double eng_2_n2;
    double thr_1_pos;
    double thr_2_pos;
    double yoke_x_pos;
    double yoke_y_pos;
    double rudder_pedal_pos;
    double rudder_pos;
    double elevator_pos;
    double aileron_pos;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;   
    double velocity_body_x;
    double velocity_body_y;
    double velocity_body_z;
    double rotation_velocity_body_x;
    double rotation_velocity_body_y;
    double rotation_velocity_body_z;    
};
```

Receiving end:

```
while (kill_dataproc == FALSE) {
    if(master == FALSE) {
        char* buffer = new char[4096];
        int recvd = recv(data_sock, buffer, 4096, NULL);
        if (recvd == 4096) {                    
            int sz = sizeof(aircraft_data);
            int intsz = sizeof(int);
            int newpacketsigner = 0;                
            memcpy_s(&newpacketsigner, intsz, buffer, intsz);
            if (newpacketsigner == 1192) {
                memcpy_s(cdata, sz, (void*)(buffer + intsz), sz); //cdata is another struct of the same type - this part works, it usually doesn't get here.                                                            

            }           
        }
        delete buffer;
    }
    Sleep(50);
}
```

The sending end (called as part of a callback function):

```
char* buff = new char[4096];
int packet_signer = 1192;
int sz = sizeof(aircraft_data);
int intsz = sizeof(int);
memcpy_s(buff, intsz, &packet_signer, intsz);
memcpy_s((void*)(buff + intsz), sz, data, sz);
send(data_sock, (char*)buff, 4096, NULL);
delete buff;
```

The server (done in a loop - the method works, as I've done it with other binary servers (i.e. VoIP):

```
char* fbuffer = new char[4096];
int recvdf = recv(gp->users[i].sockfd_data, fbuffer, 4096, NULL);
if (recvdf > 0)
    gp->send_to_all(fbuffer, i, 1, recvdf);
delete fbuffer;
```

I feel it pertinent to add that if I attempt to set TCP_NODELAY on any of the sockets, it causes the same issue, and reducing the Sleep() time of the sending thread seems to cause it too.

Comment: Is your problem that `newpacketsigner` is never 1192 on the receiving end? If so then it's probably a byte ordering problem. Try `ntohl(newpacketsigner)`.

Comment: Well, it's sometimes 1192 (in the first couple), then suddenly stops, and the buffer seems to be full of a single character (when it's read as a char* by VS - and it's always the same, after the real packets stop).

Comment: A reasonably simple portable version would be to write each variable in the struct to a byte array, and to read the variables out in the same order on the receiver.  Anything else is VERY risky-  even a different set of compiler options can break it.

Comment: Any reason why you're sending 4k of data each time? Your struct isn't that big so you're just sending a bunch of garbage data following each real bit of data. I'm not saying this is causing your problem (maybe) but seems like a big waste. Are you able to sniff out what's going on using Ethereal or some such tool?

Comment: I'm sending 4K as it's sent in rapid succession - I was having an issue with it where the TCP socket would stream the messages together, so I couldn't read them separate - the 4096 packet size guarantees separation of it (although, I was considering cutting it WAY back).

Comment: "the 4096 packet size guarantees separation of it" -- no, there is no guarantee here.  You need a loop like `for (totRecvd = 0; totRecvd < 4096; ) { recvd = recv(sock, &fbuffer[totRecvd], ...); if (0 < recvd) totRecvd += recvd; else ... }`

Comment: @nodakai is right - you must use a proper protocol on top of TCP to transfer messages over the byte stream,  You have built undefined behaviour into your network comms.

Comment: So, it is the oversized buffer causing the issue? Wireshark seems to show packets of different size coming in, along with the 1024 len ones.

Comment: @Collin: TCP is a streaming protocol, it doesn't have "messages" only a stream of bytes. You can never rely on the packets received being the same size as the ones sent, whatever the size you sent. You need to handle message reassembly on the receiving side (which is easy if the packets are always the same size).

Comment: Funny title for the post. Sometimes works... and sometimes it doesn't :D

Comment: You should always be sending packets of size `(sizeof(int)+sizeof(aircraft_data))`, and reading data of the same size on the receiving end.

Comment: The combination of the comments I upvoted seemed to fix it - I'm now sending and receiving a buffer of size (sizeof(int) + sizeof(aircraft_data)) and it's receiving it valid on both ends now. I seem to have made a mistake somewhere else, however, as it's receiving the same packet over and over again.

Comment: Don't use structs as network protocols. You are introducing at least half a dozen dependencies. Define yourself a wire protocol in octets and write yourself a library to send and receive it.

Comment: Also consider using a networking library such as boost::asio - that handles a lot of things for you. Such as scaling the server and demuxing the data.

Comment: It's ok to use structs. But you need an accurate bookkeeping with alignment and byte order.

Use #pragma pack(1) to solve alignment issues:

#pragma pack(1)
struct aircraft_data {
};
#pragma pack()

Comment: @SGrebenkin It's not 'OK to use structs'. Name one well-known TCP protocol that does it. There are at least six reasons against it, not to mention the fact that the OP's code doesn't work in the first place so he might as well redo it on a proper basis.

Comment: @EJP For. ex: http://www.jbox.dk/sanos/source/include/net/tcp.h.html . Basically, there is nothing wrong if you do it carefully. The only requirement - one should do it with correct byte-order, alignment and use POD-structure. Why shouldn't I use it, if I reach my aim? What are those 6 reasons?

Comment: @SGrebenkin Basically there is nothing wrong with it if you can control, at both ends, the hardware, the compiler, the compiler version, the compiler options, the struct definition itself, the surrounding #pragmas, ...

Comment: @EJP you don't need to 'control' them, just document what byte ordering & packing should be, and stick to it. If your compiler supports the documented settings, you can use a struct, otherwise you need to do it more 'manually'